# How to require a specific object with Flow

Tags: javascript, graphql, flowtype

I'm trying to figure out how to set a property type to be a specific object.

Or, to be more clear about my specific situation --- I'm injecting all of my models into GraphQL's context object. Each of the models are simple objects that look like:

```
const getUser = (id: string): UserType => db.collections('User').find({ id })

const User = {
  getUser,
  // ...etc
}
```

A resolver would look like:

```
const user = (_: Object, args: GetUserArgs, ctx: GraphQLContext) => {
    ctx.models.User.getUser(args.input.id)
}
```

I could type GraphQLContext like this:

```
type UserModel = {
  getUser: (id: string): UserType
  // ... etc, for each function. But I've already typed `getUser` above.
}

type Models = {
  user: UserModel
}

type GraphQLContext = {
  models: Models
}
```

But, this seems tedious and error-prone as functions I'm adding to my models grow and change during development. Is there a way that I can type the models property that would get all of the type definitions that are already applied to each function? In other words, is there a way I can do this without having to type getUser in both places?

[Here's an example](https://flow.org/try/#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-bwPgRvnFUoESAAJShGFwn2Q8BmZ0FxlcnooUjl3ie1n49nUxXmBhSyCzFtzy0aAH0+EGQyRxGxuuXFho+KwhxW+AKS7QyxXIBoB5Mp8KhuKpT1ELLaUwvKtfCR-IFJoj4-VEa5EWTaE1h4juLTTkA)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `typeof` operator to get the type of your model objects.

```
const User = {
  getUser
}

const Models = {
  User
}

type GraphQLContext = {  
  models: typeof Models
}
```

I implemented the idea in [your example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKhCgAIUhVBnApgJ0gWQPYBNEBsojDjgAuAngA6JxLIAql1AvJAN5SQCWWAXJPCWScAdgHMANBwCutYQEMAtoj4ChY8AF9iAYwzCBkUYhIIUkFgApuKwSNEBKPqfqNzAPjYdkxqcmGfIQK5eSAByAEYAJgBmUMkgyBkUeSU+UIUyAFoUxFCOLS1wUAhoSABBXFx0bDx4SCthACtEbRJELC5hEgxDZDkKAAsARyrWgA97AiJwXX0SGjMWdkCjE1pNHT0DTBxcOqWOZw3SVwBxPsGARQAZAGE9NrH5g8DQDkCASRw5SrJID9CHVwnAA1tRupAAEbUOSQ3DgnpYHrwDBKEgDOyQYFgnjvSAKGp7PgAEg+czkwm0iAA8gAzamQ5qtAA8O1qbg4hA4HAJu3gfHIVAwtOqfOOxQIkAASogUbgAG4oeBTYiC6inYzOMkUKTPTwASGs-Fs6kKswMSWQMrlitQlgA+nwGUySOI2J0dfMNHxWB7dXwNWsUNrdZANG7xgGLgMbvcuognvZ3AFvCRfP5xgA6Xm1TPOTOrZwNT2Z7hJ45AA)